# How can I update an "x" variable with a Key Listener?

Tags: java, swing, graphics

What I'm trying to do is practice some swing coding. I created a rectangle from scratch and gave it an x and y position on the frame. What I've been trying to do is use a key listener to update the x variable to move it left and right.

Here I created a class which implements an Action Listener:

```
    public class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
```

I added "x" and "y" variables:

```
int x, y;
int dx;
int HEIGHT, WIDTH;
private final int DELAY = 50;
```

Next are some additional functions:

```
    public Board() {

    setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    setFocusable(true);
    setDoubleBuffered(true);
    addKeyListener(new TAdapter());

    x = 15;
    y = 150;
    dx = 5;    //This is what I want to use to update the x variable if possible.

    HEIGHT = 15;
    WIDTH = 15;

}
```

This is where I created the square with said "x" and "y" variables:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);

    int red = 103;
    int green = 10;
    int blue = 100;
    Color square = new Color(red, green, blue);


    g.setColor(square);
    g.fillRect(x, y, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
}
```

Ok, now onto what I'm trying to accomplish.

I created a "move" method that will be fed into the Action Performed method and then I created a Key Adapter method that handles the Key Events:

```
    public void move() {
        x += dx;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    move();
    repaint();
}


private class TAdapter extends KeyAdapter {

    public void KeyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            dx = 1;
        }

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            dx = -1;
        }
    }   
}
```

Here's a screenshot of what I'm getting:

[image: black window with small purple square in the left side]

Everything manifests through another class, but all that does is initialize the various JFrame components (size, visibility, etc.) and starts the program.

When I run the program I cannot get the x variable to update. Can someone let me know what I need to add?

Thanks.

Comment: My suggestion regarding use of a KeyListener: **don't**. Use [key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead for this. The tutorial will explain why this is important and how to use these.

Comment: The KeyAdapter will not update your UI, and actionPerformed will not be called on keys. You need to refresh your UI to reflect the changes.

Comment: Also, google 'Killer Game Programming in Java', it's a bit of an older book, but there are free ebook versions, and the first few chapters build up a nice robust game loop that you can use.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that your actionPerformed method is not getting called, so your move() method is not getting called either. You are not adding an ActionListener to anything, so it would not get called at all. I would call both move() and repaint() in keyPressed like this

```
if( key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT ) {
    dx = 1;
    move();
    repaint();
}

if( key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT ) {
    dx = -1;
    move();
    repaint();
}
```

I'm pretty sure that would work.
There are also two things I see with your code that I'd like to point out. Firstly, keyPressed has a lowercase k, not an uppercase one. Secondly, the way you've used dx with the buttons, if you press the left button, the square would move to the right; it would go in the opposite direction. Also, just like what dann.dev mentioned in his comment, read at least the first chapter in that book. It gives you tips on double-buffering, multithreading in video games, and it gives a nice loop you could use.